# sqlalchemy postgresql "Is Null" index

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How can you create an `IS NULL` index using sqlalchemy on PostgreSQL?

PostgreSQL [supports this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-types.html):

> an IS NULL or IS NOT NULL condition on an index column can be used with a B-tree index.

I've tried the following:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    processing_start_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        Index('processing_null_index', 'processing_start_time', is_null=True),
    )
```

I get this error:

```
/foo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py:291: SAWarning: Can't validate argument 'is_null'; can't locate any SQLAlchemy dialect named 'is'
  (k, dialect_name))
```

Comment: What is `is_null = true` supposed to be?  Just put the column you care about in the index.  Let Postgres take care of parsing and using the index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes that would work but be slower. postgres specifically supports a more optimal "IS NULL" index type and I'd like to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IS NULL` is not a separate index type. `IS NULL` in this specific case is a condition expression on a [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html). You can declare partial indices for PostgreSQL in SQLAlchemy via the [`postresql_where`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#partial-indexes) kwarg:

```
Index('processing_null_index', processing_start_time, postgresql_where=processing_start_time.is_(None))
```

Comment: This is a really reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: If your column isn't already defined in model you can always pass it to postgresql_where as Column('processing_start_time') or with sql 'schema_name.table_name.processing_start_time IS NOT NULL'